# Extrair tabela de um site para Rstudio

Tags: r, dataset

Olá, quero pegar a tabela do brasileirao, por exemplo desse site "http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/" e extrair para um dateset no Rstudio, de forma que sempre que a tabela atualizar conforme os jogos, ela se atualize no rstudio também. Algúem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para isso eu costumo usar o pacote `XML`. Permite dizer qual a tabela da página web que interessa. Neste caso essa página tem várias. A terceira não tem nada de interesse, portanto extraí as números 1, 2, e 4.

```
library(XML)

URL <- "http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/"

tabela1 <- readHTMLTable(URL, which = 1)
tabela1

tabela2 <- readHTMLTable(URL, which = 2)
tabela2

tabela4 <- readHTMLTable(URL, which = 4)
tabela4
```

Note que pode usar os argumentos da função base R `read.table`, nomeadamente o argumento `stringsAsFactors` pode ser importante.